# WatchGuard WebBlocker - Can't visit any website

Tags: firewall

When I try to load any website i get this error message from the WatchGuard:

[image: Error message]

And i can see in FireWare web UI, that the webblocker feature key is expired.

[image: WebBlocker is expired]

Is this connected? Will that solve my problem to renew that license?

Answer (score 0):

The service may not actually be disabled (by you) and is still trying to reach the watchguard servers to check links. I would say you need to either renew the subscription or enable the license bypass setting. The bypass setting on my XTM Device' Web UI is located at Subscription Services -> WebBlocker -> Advanced and in there you should see "License Bypass". If you cannot do it from there, load up Policy Manager and navigate through to your subscription services, webblocker, configure and you should see the license bypass feature, you need to change it from "Deny" to "Allowed" and that should fix your issues.